# Spring mvc 3.2: NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Deque

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jboss

On processing get request to my @Controller method i get

```
    2013-01-10 18:16:44,871 INFO  [STDOUT] 2013-01-10 18:16:44 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-53] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processRequest - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/Deque
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1259) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [javaee.jar:9.1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796) [spring-webmvc-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [javaee.jar:9.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.5.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.5.0_25]
```

I use spring 3.2, java 5, jboss 4.2

**EDIT**
Problem was in thymeleaf and not in spring

Comment: i was under impression spring supports java 5 :( Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: [Spring homepage](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) states "requires Java 1.5+". Look like they made some blunder. Your current best bet seems to be downgrading to 3.1, 3.0 or even 2.5 or whatever is *really* Java 1.5 compatible.

Comment: also see this: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?115616-java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-java-util-Deque-%28Spring-3-0-2-on-WAS-6-1-w-JRE-1-5%29

Comment: So it look like that whole 3.x is not Java 1.5 compatible at all. Well, then rest downgrading to 2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

Issue was with thymeleaf 2.0.13. It was compiled with java 5 (i checked with javap - 49) but uses java.util.Deque. I upgraded to 2.0.15 and issue is gone. 
I apologize to Spring guys, they're doing incredible job.

i feel chest pain now

Answer (score 1):

Deque

Since:
    1.6

Check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 1):

you are using an older java version than 1.6 ? Deque has only been around since then apparently.

I would guess your dev environment uses a new jvm, whilst your deployment is older, thats why the error does not appear at compile time.

Update your java version where you deploy your spring app.